# How to extract output data from CMD using C++?

Tags: c++

im using this:

```
system("netsh wlan show profiles");
```

That command output the profiles on interface WLAN on the console
and what i want to know is if there's a way to copy a user profile name from the console into a varibale.

Comment: You can't. You'll need a `fork()`, a `pipe()`, and one of the `execxyz()` functions to do that.

Comment: Look into the [`_popen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-160) function.